# In which way Node.js handles jobs in parallel? [Bull v3]

Tags: node.js, jobs, worker, bull

I have started experimenting in `Node.js` lately.

I'm currently setting up an app, which will handle multiple **queues** in **parallel** by utilising `bull` library, to run heavy jobs in the background.

I'm looking for an answer, which i hope i did not miss in the documentation.

**It's still kind of "blurry" to me, how this library is handling those tasks in parallel. **

So i have the following scenario:

- 2 jobs are running at the same time, both of them are heavy and are
  taking some time to finish.
- During the run of those 2 jobs, i can still use the rest of the
  application - The event loop is not blocked.

What i get from that, is, that probably something else handles those 2 jobs, since `JavaScript` is `single-threaded`  **What is this?**

Any guidance or any advice will be highly appreciated!

https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

Comment: Bull uses child_process.fork to spawn new processes. See https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/edfbd163991c212dd6548875c22f2745f897ae28/lib/process/child-pool.js#L3 and https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: JS runtime is single-threaded but it doesn't mean you can't access [multithread API](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) from it

Comment: Thank you both! Taking a look!